# MySQL Update statement Error - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `People`, when i `describe People` i get the following output

```
| Name | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

My sql update statement :

```
update Person set Name='xxx'  AND Age= '33' ;
```

The error :

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'xxx'
```

Comment: `People` or `Person`: make up your mind :-)

Comment: Describe also the column Age please (and as is your sql is wrong)

Comment: I guess i should remove the `AND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query

`update People set Name='xxx' , Age= '33' where condition` ;

Answer (score 2):

depends on what you want to do. Setting `age` and `name` for all in your table do

```
update Person set Name='xxx', Age= '33'
```

or set `name` for all with `age=33` do

```
update Person set Name='xxx' WHERE Age= '33'
```